# Why is this ggplot not working when I change the column name?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was troubleshooting why a particular ggplot was not working, and after comparing with the test data below, it seems like the problematic factor is the name of the columns I had chose. I don't have issue with the column name in other aspects of my ggplot, just when I am trying to make a vertical line at the maximum value. Why would this be happening?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2)
a<-seq(from=0,to=1000,by=5)
b<-sample(seq(from = 0, to = 100), size = 201, replace = TRUE)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
df2<-data.frame(a,b)


colnames(df2) <- c("log_trend", "Kappa")
  stat_density(size=1.2,color='grey40') +
  geom_vline(xintercept= max(a),color='red')

#works


ggplot(data=df2,aes(x=log_trend)) + 
  stat_density(size=1.2,color='grey40') +
  geom_vline(xintercept= max(log_trend),color='red')


#Error in list2(...) : object 'log_trend' not found
```

Comment: `log_trend` is a column of the data.frame df2, hence you have to do `geom_vline(xintercept= max(df2$log_trend))`. In your first code `a` is also the name of a vector and it is this vector which is used in `geom_vline(xintercept= max(a),color='red')` not the data.frame column `df$a`.

Comment: Or wrap in `aes`, like `+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept = max(log_trend))`.